# Left and right adjoints of restriction in modules.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules, adjoint-functors

Given a map $f:A\rightarrow B$ of rings, we get a functor $Res_f:\text{B-Mod}\rightarrow \text{A-Mod}$, induced by our map $f$. This has left adjoint $B\otimes_A \text{_}$ where the $B$ module structure is given by multiplication on the first factor. We also have a right adjoint $Hom_A(B,\text{_})$, where we premultiply to give the $B$ module structure.

If $B/A$ is free, then these functors are isomorphic, though it seems we need to pick a basis of $B/A$ to exhibit this.

Are these functors still isomorphic if $B$ is locally free over $A$?

Really, this is trying to understand the difference between the left and right adjoints of $f_\ast$ for a map of schemes, but I am more comfortable in the commutative algebra/modules setting, hence phrasing in this manner.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you state your Hom-tensor adjunction statement? I don't see why the right adjoint is $Hom_A(B,-)$. Isn't your $B$ $X$ in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor-hom_adjunction?

Comment: Sure, the usual Tensor-Hom adjuction is exhibiting $Res_f$ as a right adjoint of $B\otimes_A$, so $Hom_{B-mod}(B\otimes_A M,N)\cong Hom_{A-mod}(M,Res_f N)$. However we can also express $Res_f$ as a left adjoint as $Hom_{A-mod}(Res_f M,N)\cong Hom_{B-mod}(M,hom_A(B,N))$. This the same situation as induction/coinduction functors in representation theory.

Comment: This [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/300531) may be of help.